# @search.results = [] when using sunspot_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

It seems that view's search form can certainly cast the search word, but 
@search.results equals []. 
And when I check Solr admin, reindex looks go well but I cannot search here, too.
Please give me your advice.

Showing relevant files below.

### messages_controller.rb

```
def index
   @search = Message.all.search do
     fulltext params[:search]
   end
   @messages = @search.results
end
```

### message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  searchable do
    string :content
  end
end
```

### home.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag messages_path, :method => :get do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
          <% end %>
```

### routes.rb

```
  resources :messages, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
searchable do
  string :content
end
```

To:

```
searchable do
  text :content
end
```

From the doc: text fields will be full-text searchable. Other fields (e.g., integer and string) can be used to scope queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But it doesn't work. Message model's content type is string.

class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id